# HornetQ - How to manage Consumers of 'Message Grouping'

Tags: parallel-processing, message-queue, producer-consumer, hornetq, message-driven-bean

After sending several messages with a Group-ID set (**message grouping**), how can I manage their delivery, to have a consumer for each Group-ID?

And how does it works if my Message Consumer is a **Message-Driven Bean**?

The idea is to implement parallel-processing for each Group-ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will ellect a Group-id randomically based on your consumers...

if you have a message driven bean, you will have multiple consumers per MDBs... each grouopID will be delivered to a single consumer.

if you ned to elect  your consumer.. simply don't use message groups.. just use selectors.

The use-case of message grouping is to automatically manage the consumer selection. If you want to bound to a specific consumer just set a property and use filters.. that's what they are for.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand that the server does all the "election", and I don't have to worry with that!

Comment: If that satisfies your question I would appreciate accepting the answer please :)

Comment: I just post edited my answer to notice you about the possibility of using message selectors on specific consumers